# Strange error while redirecting using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hashbang

Long story short I'm trying to redirect:

```
http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/onetwothree
```

to something like this:

```
http://example.com/serve.php?_escaped_fragment_=/onetwothree
```

I'm using following .htaccess code:

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  _escaped_fragment_=  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/serve.php$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

But the response is quite weird:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /serve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpserve.phpindex.html.var on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm new to this. I would really appreciate your help.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  _escaped_fragment_=  [NC]
RewriteCond $1 ^serve\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/serve.php$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

But now it's not working at all. When I try to access `example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/dfas` it redirects me to `example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/dfas#!` instead of `example.com/serve.php?_escaped_fragment_=dfas` Please help me guys I've no idea why this is happening. It's really important for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that you've not already been redirected to serve.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  _escaped_fragment_=  [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^serve\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/serve.php$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Now i'm unable to redirect to the serve.php file... It's redirecting to http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/dfas#! instead of http://example.com/serve.php?_escaped_fragment_=dfas